# Verifying an exe file

Tags: c#, code-signing

I understand for the most part how signing an exe using the Microsoft signtool works. I have an exe (C#) that I want to only run if the file has not been modified, and if I understand correctly, this can verify that. What I don't understand is how to verify the file. If my code to verify the file is built inside the exe I am verifying, couldn't one just decompile the exe, remove the code that checks the file, and re-compile it?

My understanding of code signing is essentially this:
[image]

Image credit to:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

But I don't see how one couldn't just take the mechanism that checks the file's integrity out of the file entirely, and run the program after it has been modified.

Comment: I'm confused, you talking about C# and Microsoft, then link an Apple documentation page?

Comment: I'm sorry, I just thought that that was the best image explaining code-signing in general, but yes I am not using Apple or xcode, I'm using C# and windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, someone may do this, but not you are responsible to verify the code. The CLR does it automatically for dlls that have a public key token. If the public key doesn't match the file hash, the CLR will not load the file.
Simply give your exe a strong name and you will be safe.

Comment: Thanks, but my fear is that couldn't someone just use delcert to remove the certificate entirely, and then just modify the program?

Comment: Yes, he can. But he cannot impersonate to you, because his strong name will differ from yours. So you can publish your strong name/company name and instruct the users to trust software signed by you only.

Answer (score -2):

If I have understood you well, you want to inject some code into existing exe application, right? If so, the best is to learn more about code injection, how to manipulate with the exe files( in general this is very easy, since adding new code to the existing code in application doesn't require much fuss about it as it would require with altering existing one ). And yes, you would have to learn assembler since it's the only way to communicate with the existing exe. You wouldn't have to compile anything, since the exe is formed in that way that it only acts as a wrapper and starter of the objects/code inside of it( that's why it's much easier to input new code, rather than manipulate with the existing one, no errors will occur if you mess up with your code whatsoever). For start, get some good book about assembler or take IDA and examine some code of the app you have got.

Comment: Your answer has nothing to do with the question asked. Also, when you post answers (or questions) here, please use paragraph breaks so that your post is readable. Walls of text (big, unbroken blocks) are hard to read and understand. Thanks. :-)

Comment: Sorry, What I meant is that I have developed a program in C# Which I have compiled into an exe application. I want this application to be able to check itself to see if it has been modified before launching itself. In other words, I sign the file on my server, and the file is downloaded. User A launches the program, and it checks its integrity. If User A has modified the exe, it won't run. If User A hasn't modified it, it will run.

Comment: If it helps, I am developing a game (Its already finished), and I am in the process of making it more difficult to cheat (it works over a network). So I am trying to make sure that the average user can't modify the client easily.

Comment: Aha, it's very late so I saw completely different situation here. As for you Q. now, I would use MD5 checksums and if anything is been altered in it ( based on the altering the exe ), make a call to my app not to be run. Simply as that. ;)

Comment: What I believe I am looking for is how to implement a secure way of "code-signing." After some research, I understand it can be used to verify the integrity of your code. But I don't understand how to verify this code securely. How would one make a system of verifying the signature where the code that verifies this signature could't just be removed from the exe entirely?